# Jquery Validation

Tags: jquery-validate

How to valid all zero number using jquery ... ex: 0000000

Comment: Can you explain in detail if i have given wrong, if u want validate the given input is 0 just sum the input and check equal to 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 jQuery.validator.addMethod(
  "invalidPin",
  function (value, element) {
      if ($('#Pin').attr('checked') == true) {
          if (element.value == 0 || element.value == undefined || element.value == '') {
              return false;
          }
          else
              return true;
      }
      else return true;
  });

 $('#create').validate({ ignore: ":not(:visible)",
                rules: {
                    AccountNumber: {
                        required: "#Pin:checked",
                        regex: "[A-Za-z0-9\-]+",
                        invalidPin: true
                    }
                               },
                messages: {
                    AccountNumber: {
                        required: "<br/>Please Enter Account Number",
                        regex: "<br/>Please Enter valid Account Number",
                        invalidPin: "<br/>Please Enter valid Account Number"
                    }

                }
            });
```